# Online Tutorial Help? Char array length not specified

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Im trying to learn how to program in C++ through the medium of games, i've already learnt my basics, so i have moved on to this website, [The Penguin Programmer](https://sites.google.com/site/thepenguinprogrammer/c-hangman-tutorial/game) To learn how to re-create hangman in C++, but reading through this tutorial, i'm not sure whether the author has made an error, or perhaps im implementing it incorrectly, never the less:

The author asks me to create a global char array - knownLetters, however he doesn't specify the length of the array, and says it could be of any length, is this an error on his part or mine?

Code:

```
char knownLetters[]; // The word could be of any length
```

Which produces the error:

```
error: storage size of 'knownLetters' isn't known
```

page of website::
[The Penguin Programmer: Hangman!](https://sites.google.com/site/thepenguinprogrammer/c-hangman-tutorial/game2)

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::vector<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to create an array of `char`s of unknown length:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> knownLetters(word.size());

// later on…
knownLetters[pos] = guess;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when i try and insert the vector into my program i get this error:  'vector' in namespace 'std' does not name a type|

Comment: @JosephSmith `#include <vector>`

Comment: Rookie mistake, my bad. Thanks for the answer friend. I'll set it as the answer when i can.

Comment: Also, this will not really work with what you're trying to do in the tutorial, @JosephSmith - later on, it asks you to do `knownLetters[pos] = userGuess;` which will fail, because the vector is of length 0, and `pos` will end up out of bounds. `push_back` will add the letters to the vector, but they won't end up at correct positions (they'll get appended at the end). The best bet would be to explicitly declare `std::vector<char> knownLetters(word.length());` and go from there.

Comment: Another option would be `std::unordered_set<char>`, given the casus (though it requires slightly different lookup code).

Comment: @rightfold - it needs to be ordered, though, so that you can compare the actual word with the guessed word on a letter-by-letter basis while printing. Which is weird, but I didn't write this tutorial ;)

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I tried word.length before, but i didn't use a vector so that's probably why it didn't work, perhaps i should use a different tutorial ? ;-)

Comment: Weeeeell... This one is not so great. But if you use vector, you should be fine, unless the author screwed something up later on :)

Comment: You usually want to use a set data structure to store the guessed letters in a hangman game (you cannot have the same letter multiple times, and a set guarantees this), as well as [standard algorithm implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) instead of explicit loops and checks.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can't do that. You can, however, do:

```
char knownLetters[] = "asdf";
```

so that the word could be of any length, *as long as it's used to initialize the array*.

Comment: Beware that this solution doesn’t allow an arbitrary number of `char`s to be added to the array at runtime; there’s place for just five `char`s.